# Keras image data ordering

Tags: tensorflow, theano, keras, pre-trained-model

When using a Theano backend in Keras, is it always necessary to use a 'channels_first' image data ordering? Or can we also use 'channels_last' as well and the Theano backend takes care of any conversions?

Comment: You should always use `channels_first` with Theano. Remember to also reshape your data.

Comment: If I use channels_first, wouldn't my data already be in (3, x, x) format? Is a reshape required?

Comment: If you read images through OpenCV or Scikit-image, Keras would not know anything about it. So yes, you have to reshape the data appropriately.